# Error Invalid id in SalesForce when adding new account

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app

I trying to add new row in Account object. 
My code :

```
 if(inputvalues[14].length() > 16)
              {a.ParentId = inputvalues[14].replaceAll('"','').replaceAll(' ','');   }
```

I read inputvalues[14] from csv file that have string

> ```
> "Apteka test",...,"", "0015E00000aWUF4QAO"
> ```

and i get by select from acccount that id `0015E00000aWUF4QAO` is true.
But i get issue : `Invalid id: 0015E00000aWUF4QAO`
Where is a problem?

Comment: Can you try using trim(), looks like there are invisible spaces.

Secondly that a record with that Id should exisit in that enviornment.

Comment: Are you running this in the test environment ?

Comment: Thank, Pranary! These were invisible spaces, trim() have helped me

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Please add answer as your comment seems to have helped the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The string has leading/ trailing whitespaces that made ID to look invalid. Using trim() on that string helps getting rid of those.